# Sum all html fields money values

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function to sum values with same ID; [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/La18Lcns/3/). This works, but not if is a decimal value, like a money value. (10,05 + 1.005,10, example)

```
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
    var MaxSelectionNum = "7";
    var sum = 0;

    // Loop through all inputs with names that start
    // with "option-quantity" and sum their values
    $('input[name^="option-quantity"]').each(function()
    {
        console.log(parseInt($(this).val()));
        sum += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
    });

    if (sum < MaxSelectionNum)
    {
        $(".errorQuantity").html("Please select 7 meals").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".errorQuantity").html("You have select greater than 7: meal count:  " + sum).show();
    }
});
```

How can we fix it?

Comment: very simple, just use parseFloat that's it :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt` when dealing with decimal values.

`parseInt()` function parses a string argument and returns an integer or NaN. If not NaN, the returned value will be the integer representation of the string passed in.

`parseFloat()` function parses a string argument and returns a floating point number or Nan(If the string expression cannot be converted to a numerical value).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/La18Lcns/7/embedded/result/) is a working sample.

Answer (score 1):

You must use **parseFloat**:

just replace your current code with the following one:

```
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
    var MaxSelectionNum = "7";
    var sum = 0;

    // Loop through all inputs with names that start
    // with "option-quantity" and sum their values
    $('input[name^="option-quantity"]').each(function()
    {
        console.log(parseFloat($(this).val()));
        sum += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    });

    if (sum < MaxSelectionNum)
    {
        $(".errorQuantity").html("Please select 7 meals").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".errorQuantity").html("You have select greater than 7: meal count:  " + sum).show();
    }
});
```

This gonna help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your script a bit (js lines 10-16)

https://jsfiddle.net/La18Lcns/10/

If you want to use number taplate such as

```
1.142,32
23.456,5
1.500
```

First you need to conver it to float format

```
1142.32
23456.5
1500
```

Than you use `parseFloat()` instead `ParseInt()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button-cart').on('click', function()
{
    var MaxSelectionNum = "7";
    var sum = 0;

    // Loop through all inputs with names that start
    // with "option-quantity" and sum their values
    $('input[name^="option-quantity"]').each(function()
    {
        console.log(parseFloat($(this).val()));
        sum += parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
    });

    if (sum < MaxSelectionNum)
    {
        $(".errorQuantity").html("Please select 7 meals").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(".errorQuantity").html("You have select greater than 7: meal count:  " + sum).show();
    }
});
```